# UnsupportedClassVersion - JacksonAutoDiscoverable

Tags: jersey, websphere, ibm-rad

I'm trying to use IBM Rational Application Developer version 9.0 with WebSphere Application Server v7.0 running Java 1.6 and use JAX-RS with org.glassfish.jersey version 2.6. This is not a maven project, so I created another maven project, added the root dependencies there and built it so it pulled down all of the jars. I moved them over into my non-maven project.

When I run the project, I start the server (or try to hit a resource) I get the following error message: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/internal/JacksonAutoDiscoverable, offset=6

I have a different application that successfully uses jersey deployed WAS7 on this same machine. I've compared the project and server configurations and see no major difference, particularly no difference in the Installed JRE", Execution Environments or Java Compiler Compliance Level (all using 1.6).

Even though the maven project is using jersey 2.6, I have also tried other lower jersey versions in the non-maven project to see if it's an issue with the dependencies being built for 1.7 but that doesn't seem to be the case at all.

Here is the list of dependencies I have in my library:

```
aopalliance-repackaged-2.2.0.jar
hk2-api-2.2.0.jar
hk2-locator-2.2.0.jar
hk2-utils-2.2.0.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar
javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.inject-2.2.0.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
jersey-client-2.6.jar
jersey-common-2.6.jar
jersey-container-servlet-core-2.6.jar
jersey-guava-2.6.jar
jersey-media-json-jackson-2.6.jar
jersey-server-2.6.jar
osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```